# Can't display the date correctly in a file generated by a cronjob

Tags: debian, cron

I'm doing a cronjob task which creates a daily database backup. To desctinct the daily files, I name them as follows: dump- (the current date). The backup operation went well, but the date is not interpreted as it should be `(dump-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d'))` instead of `dump-14-12-2018`.

```
#filename=dump-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
#*/3 * * * * cd /bdd-backups/ && mysqldump --all-databases > 
$filename.sql -u xxx -pxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what your problem is,
since you show us a file that's 80% commented out,
but it looks like you are treating the crontab file
as if it were a multi-line shell script. 
It's not; each line is a self-contained, independent entity. 
So you cannot assign a value to a variable on one line
and use it on another line.

Either put everything on one line, or —
and this is probably better in the long run —
put the `date`, `cd` and `mysqldump` commands into a separate script file,
and run the script from crontab.